# What is カッコマン here?

Tags: translation

最近の家電はブルーライト推しですな♪(´ε｀ )宇宙船ぽくてカッコマン(^-^)/

http://lockerz.com/s/121398862

What does カッコマン mean?

What does はブルーライト推し turn into in English?

What does that whole thing say?

Answer (score 2):

As for the `カッコ` part, it is pretty much obvious that it is shortened from `格好いい` (kakko(o) ii) 'cool'. I am not sure about the `マン` part.

`ブルーライト推し` means 'to favour blue light LED'.

The whole translation (except the `マン` part) is:

> Recent household electronics use blue light LEDs so often. They look like spacecrafts, and are cool.

The background here is that a blue light LED is a recent invention, and until then, LED lamps seen on electronics were either green or red, or a color synthesized from them, like yellow, orange, etc., and introduction of blue light LEDs changed the appearance of household elecrtonics.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be "Mr. Brackets", the smiley with brackets that comes after?

Comment: @Axioplase Because 'it is cool since it looks like a spacecraft' will make sense but '(Mr.) parentheses for looking like a spacecraft' does not make sense. Also, (unlike in US/Europe, where the facemark is usually turned), using a pair of parentheses to describe an upright facemark is the standard in Japan so that it does not make sense to call a particular example of it 'Mr. parentheses'.

Comment: Well, I must be the only one to (sometimes) comment my smileys when I use them then :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be saying that he's a "Cool Man" for having a telephone with a blue light?

> 最近の家電

"Latest/Newest Telephone"

ETA: Actually, that's slang, just noticed.  Probably just means random "consumer electronic device", since it doesn't really look like a phone ^_-

> ブルーライト推しですな

"Has a blue light, yeah!"

> 宇宙船

"Spaceship"

> ぽくて

Trash?

> カッコマン

KakkoMan = Cool Man, seems to be a shortened version of かっこつけマン

Maybe he found it in the trash?  Not sure...

Comment: Where does 'telephone' come from? Where does 'trash' come from? Why does the man have to `かっこつける` 'make himself look cool'?

Comment: 家電 - http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E5%AE%B6%E9%9B%BB&eng=&dict=edict

いえでん　slang for Telephone... though it probably is just "consumer electronics".. corrected.

Comment: ぽくて is the "te" form of ぽい which is "to throw away" or "get rid of".  かっこつけマン "kakkotsuke man" is slang for a man who "puts on airs" as it were.

Comment: `っぽい` is an affix meaning 'resemble'.

Comment: I have never heard of `家電` meaning telephone, although I can imagine that it may mean a telephone installed in a house as opposed to public phones and cell phones. But it will not mean simply telephone. Moreover, if there is such word, it would be a jargon than a slang; it's too rare. How would "put on airs" make sense in this context?

Comment: "puts on airs" simply means someone trying a bit too hard to be cool.  "oooh, I have a blue led device, aren't I just awesome!?"

Comment: @sawa: As you guessed, いえでん is a slang which means home phone as opposed to cell phone.  I do not know how the word is usually written, because I have only heard it in speech.  But 家電 in the question does not refer to いえでん.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi_Ito Agree. It is obvious that it is not this usage. Also, a more popular word would be `固定電話`.

Comment: @sawa いえでん is quite common among young speakers, so I wouldn't find it out of context per se, but I agree that in this case it's probably かでん since 1. the picture doesn't at all look like a phone and 2. I think people would shy away from writing いえでん as 家電 because of the obvious confusion.